# Unable to send ether from a contract to an account

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

I am unable to send ether from the following contract to a recipient address.

```
contract MoneyFountain{

    address owner;
    uint256 sendAmount;

    function MoneyFountain(){
        owner = msg.sender;
        sendAmount = 100000000000000000;
    }

    function getBalance() returns (uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function sendWei(address recp) returns (bool){        
        recp.send(sendAmount);
    }
}
```

I am able to put this contract on a private blockchain and also populate the contract balance to 10 ethers to begin with.

```
web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x171fa8740cbd7ffaec96109b5d35172556a96886"),"e}
```

> 10

After the successful execution of the function `sendWei()`, if I check the balance of the recipient it doesn't show the balance to be transferred. The contract and the balance of the recipient remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if (!recp.send(sendAmount))
throw;
```

instead    `recp.send(sendAmount);`

and use `this.balance` without address

also check the balance before sending

```
if(address(this).balance>sendAmount){
    if (!recp.send(sendAmount)){
        throw;
    return false;
    } 
    else {
    return true;
    }
```

to check you could use an event :

```
  event send_amount(address indexed _to,uint _value);
```

so the code will look like :

```
contract MoneyFountain{

address owner;
uint256 sendAmount;

function MoneyFountain(){
    owner = msg.sender;
    sendAmount = 100000000000000000;
}

function getBalance() returns (uint){
    return address(this).balance;
}    
event send_amount(address indexed _to,uint indexed _value);

    function sendWei(address recp) returns (bool){

    if(this.balance>sendAmount){
            if (!recp.send(sendAmount)){
                throw;
            return false;
            } 
            else {
               send_amount(recp,sendAmount);
            return true;
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: actually, I stripped down to the recp.send from the above code snippets as no exceptions were being thrown and still the ether weren't getting transferred.

Comment: are you working on a private chain? if so you need to mine the transaction

Comment: Yes, these are mined. That is how i know they are successful, they give valid transaction hashes.

Comment: Result: {
  "blockHash": "0xa4ae150e0c84aafbf1b5bd477354e0c0c9c9718b159c1a9b6023b97cd8a1f7bd",
  "blockNumber": 2243,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 54787,
  "from": "0x50e6abb4972d92d025b2da4fc11fe4e9148a7c14",
  "gasUsed": 54787,
  "logs": [],
  "root": "33a0a75d15529838ecc004265d6cbf4de40732a1ab2c5929bfca2430fdf1782d",
  "to": "0x29e3f0899fbf98fccf2f7ffdd926733c84c18b15",
  "transactionHash": "0x19b52c643b659e97537f849a4cb77dc6221a1f43ae0c0a0054bdce605a6f66ac",
  "transactionIndex": 0
}
Transaction cost: 54787 gas.

Comment: i will test it localy and give you the result

Comment: did this work for you locally?

Comment: i ve made some change it works now in geth local  i ve removed address from this.balance